# How to Validate Trello Webhook Signatures in Golang Fiber?

Tags: go, trello, fibers

I wrote the below code by Following: https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/trello/guides/rest-api/webhooks/
Node.js Reference in Golang Fiber But Hash is not the same as Given Hash,  Anyone kindly tell me what I missed? Thanks in advance.

```
func TrelloWebhook(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    var (
        TRELLO_SECRET = "****ea6308995"
        webhookURL    = "https://*****ssum.ngrok-free.app/trello-webhook"
    )

    base64Digest := func(secret string) string {
        key := []byte(TRELLO_SECRET)
        mac := hmac.New(sha1.New, key)
        mac.Write([]byte(secret))
        return base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(mac.Sum(nil))
    }

    hashedHeader := c.Get("x-trello-webhook")
    requestBody := string(c.BodyRaw())

    doubleHashedHeader := base64Digest(hashedHeader)
    doubleHashedBody := base64Digest(base64Digest(requestBody + webhookURL))

    fmt.Println("doubleHashedHeader : ", doubleHashedHeader)
    fmt.Println("doubleHashedBody : ", doubleHashedBody)

    if hmac.Equal([]byte(doubleHashedHeader), []byte(doubleHashedBody)) {
        fmt.Println("SUCCESS")
    }
    // Your existing return statement
    return c.Status(200).JSON(&fiber.Map{
        "status":      true,
        "information": "customers-data_request!",
    })
}
```

I also tryed below ways too it's also not working

```
func TrelloWebhook(c *fiber.Ctx) error {

    secret := "****ea6308995"
    callbackURL := "https://*****ssum.ngrok-free.app/trello-webhook"

    base64Digest := func(s string) string {
        h := hmac.New(sha1.New, []byte(secret))
        h.Write([]byte(s))
        return base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(h.Sum(nil))
    }

    var request map[string]interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(c.Body(), &request); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error decoding JSON:", err)
        return c.SendStatus(fiber.StatusBadRequest)
    }

    contentBuffer := bytes.NewBuffer(c.Body())
    contentBuffer.WriteString(callbackURL)
    content := contentBuffer.String()

    doubleHash := base64Digest(content)
    headerHash := c.Get("x-trello-webhook")

    if doubleHash == headerHash {
        fmt.Println(" Working ? ")
    }

    fmt.Println("doubleHash : ", doubleHash)
    fmt.Println("headerHash : ", headerHash)

    // Your existing return statement
    return c.Status(200).JSON(&fiber.Map{
        "status":      true,
        "information": "customers-data_request!",
    })
}
```

This is another way i changed but not working

```
func TrelloWebhook(c *fiber.Ctx) error {

    secret := "****ea6308995"
    callbackURL := "https://*****ssum.ngrok-free.app/trello-webhook"

    base64Digest := func(s string) string {
        h := hmac.New(sha1.New, []byte(secret))
        h.Write([]byte(s))
        return base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(h.Sum(nil))
    }

    var request map[string]interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(c.Body(), &request); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error decoding JSON:", err)
        return c.SendStatus(fiber.StatusBadRequest)
    }

    requestBody, err := json.Marshal(request)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error encoding JSON:", err)
        return c.SendStatus(fiber.StatusInternalServerError)
    }

    content := string(requestBody) + callbackURL

    doubleHash := base64Digest(content)
    headerHash := c.Get("x-trello-webhook")

    fmt.Println("doubleHash : ", doubleHash)
    fmt.Println("headerHash : ", headerHash)

    // Your existing return statement
    return c.Status(200).JSON(&fiber.Map{
        "status":      true,
        "information": "customers-data_request!",
    })
}
```

Comment: `base64Digest(hashedHeader)` <--- why do you apply `base64Digest` to the header? Why do you apply `base64Digest` twice to request and body? Why do you not convert body to JSON string first? The JS sample code in the link you provided is different in so many ways to yours.

Comment: I read another link that told me to double encrypt that's why I did that,  Without that it also not working.